# multiple crop operations on input video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to efficiently split a video  file (2048x2048px, 100.000 frames) into multiple tiles. Typically, into four quadrants of equal size (1024x1024px, 100.000 frames).
I can go one tile after the other using ffmpeg's crop filter:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -filter:v "crop=1024:1024:0:0" out1.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.avi -filter:v "crop=1024:1024:1023:0" out2.mp4
```

etc...

can this be combined into a single command to increase execution speed?

Comment: Can this be migrated to https://video.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a single input, crop then map to multiple outputs. Example for two tiles:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=1024:1024:1023:0[out2]" \
-map [out1] -map 0:a out1.mp4 \
-map [out2] -map 0:a out2.mp4
```

Comment: I don't have audio so I slightly modified to the following:
ffmpeg -i x264In.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=1024:1024:1023:0[out2]" -map [out1] -map 0 out1.mp4 -map [out2] -map 0 out2.mp4
(I execute this as a .bat script and I had to remove all slashes)

Windows preview shows me the cropped video as out.mp4 preview but when I play the out.mp4 files, they contain the full video. What am I missing?

Comment: You got it wrong: `-map 0:a` is the audio (`a`) stream (or streams) in the input `0`. If you do `-map 0` you map all the streams in input `0`. Just omit the `-map 0:a`.

Comment: never mind, I am very new to ffmpeg and had no idea what I was doing. the correct way of getting rid of the audio is this:
ffmpeg -i x264In.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1024:1024:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=1024:1024:1023:0[out2]" -map [out1] out1.mp4 -map [out2] out2.mp4
Now it is working!

Comment: This worked for me, after I added quotes to [out1] and [out2] in the map commands. `-map "[out1]" -map 0:a out1.mp4`